# does the apple itunes api allow me to get a song programmatically?

Tags: iphone

I want to create an application that will let users get new music from the itunes store, and do it through my interface. Is it possible to do that through the exposed API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not instruct iTunes to buy something, buying is only possible via the iTunes interface.
You can, however, create links to iTunes content using *iTunes Link Maker*, and then open the according iTunes item via `-[UIApplication openURL:]`.

The links you can create via *iTunes Link Maker* refer to one specific iTunes item only, and can not be constructed on the device, so you would either have to hard-code the links, or (which i would prefer) get the links from a web service, via which you control what is displayed in the app.